# How to output the matched string in order based on the given pattern

Tags: linux, shell

For example the input is

```
abcde    
abcde1n1    
abcde0n1    
abcdf
```

What I want to search is whether abcdf/abcde exist, but output them in the order of the given pattern.

So the desired output should be:

```
abcdf    
abcde
```

I tried `cat file1.txt | grep "abcdf\|abcde"`, but it gives out abcde first.

Comment: No way to `grep -w 'abcd\(f\|e\)' file` and preserve the order of the match. Multiple calls to `grep` searching `abcdf` and then a second call searching `abcde` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does not work like that. To achieve sequencing of input , you may need to run loop through various inputs.

```
for string in abcdf abcde;
do
   grep  -w "$string" file;
done
```

Will return in this:

```
abcdf
abcde
```

`-w` flag is used here to simulate the exact desired result.

Comment: That works, or the equivalent one-liner `grep -w 'abcdf' file; grep -w 'abcde' file`